# joi schema: add keys on condition of another a fields value

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, joi

I have the following joi schema:

```js
Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),    
    params: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        type: Joi.string().valid("number", "string", "boolean").required(),
        key: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.when("type", {
            is: "number",
            then: Joi.number()
        }).when("type", {
            is: "string",
            then: Joi.string()
        }).when("type", {
            is: "boolean",
            then: Joi.boolean()
        }).allow(null).default(null)
    }))
})
```

which sets the type of "value" based on the value of the "type" field.
So far so good, its work as expected. But now i need to add additional fields to the object based on the value of "type". E.g. if `type=string`, a "default" field should be added and the final schema should looks like this:

```js
Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    params: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        key: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.string(),
        type: Joi.string().valid("number", "string", "boolean").required(),
        default: Joi.string().default("default-value")
    }))
})
```

For `type=number`:

```js
Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    params: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        key: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.number(),
        type: Joi.string().valid("number", "string", "boolean").required(),
        min: Joi.number().required().default(0),
        max: Joi.number().required().default(100),
    }))
})
```

I have tried the following but got no error, nor the result with the default values i wanted, simple, nothing changed.

```js
Joi.object({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    params: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        key: Joi.string().required(),
        value: Joi.when("type", {
            is: "number",
            then: Joi.number()
        }).when("type", {
            is: "string",
            then: Joi.string()
        }).when("type", {
            is: "boolean",
            then: Joi.boolean()
        }).allow(null).default(null),
        type: Joi.string().valid("number", "string", "boolean").required(),
    }).when("type", {
        is: "number",
        then: Joi.object({
            min: Joi.number().default(0),
            max: Joi.number().default(100)
        })
    }).when("type", {
        is: "string",
        then: Joi.object({
            default: Joi.string().default("default-value"),
        })
    }))
})
```

Whats the correct way to add additional fields based on another fields value?

I have the feeling i need to use ".concat" but i have no clue how to combine that with ".when".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you!

```
Joi.object({
  name: Joi.string().required(),
  params: Joi.array().items(
    Joi.object({
      type: Joi.string().valid('number', 'string', 'boolean').required(),
      key: Joi.string().required(),
      value: Joi.when('type', {
        is: 'number',
        then: Joi.number(),
        otherwise: Joi.when('type', {
          is: 'string',
          then: Joi.string(),
          otherwise: Joi.when('type', {
            is: 'boolean',
            then: Joi.boolean(),
          }),
        }),
      })
        .allow(null)
        .default(null)
    })
  )
});
```

PS: I haven't tested it yet but just used the nested when condition as we usually do while programming. Enjoy!